# How to get approach in teaching a subject you are fluent in but not included in your degree

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, academic-life, lecturer, lecture-teaching-method

I am a Mathematics graduate and have done a post-graduate degree too, with a research component involving a mathematical application in cryptography.

I'm currently working as a temporary lecturer in Mathematics but this is an interdisciplinary faculty and hence the number of lecture hours related to maths lectures is considerably low. Some others do visiting lectures too, but for me still couldn't find such lectures either. So I'm now getting compared with lecturers doing other subjects because they have a higher workload when thinking about the number of lecture hours. There's another Maths lecturer, she is keeping a bit of a higher load than me, and refuses to give me any of it to share further.

Even though my main subject is Mathematics, I have done an IT diploma (only a diploma though) and because I did cryptography for post-grad, I studied some computer programming too. And I anyway have some fluency in programming side, even though I don't have a complete degree like Bachelors in IT.

There's a module called "Fundamentals of computer programming" done by an IT graduate. If I'll be allowed to teach this module, my problem is getting solved. I know how to teach this well, as I have been doing programming related things all along, even though it's not mentioned in my degree transcript specifically..

He has many other lectures too, so his workload is anyway not getting affected by giving this lecture to me. Perhaps, I can even stay as a trainee under him for a couple of months and then take over, there are such things happening for other modules too when a new lecturer comes.

But how can I explain that I'm indeed fluent in teaching to my department head to get permission? Can a lecturer request to teach a subject by mentioning that it'll help career growth?

I mean the only valid explanations I can see are, to tell that,

1. I have done computer programming in my diploma as well as the post-graduate research and so I'm well aware
2. It will help my career if I'm allowed to do it, because it's a part of my post-grad specialization

Any other things I can tell them? And any other solutions?

The comparisons have come to a point that they might not be willing to keep me continuously. Still I have to settle my problem smoothly too, so that no misunderstanding occur. That's why I thought like this.

Please kindly advise me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Related: [Can a professor teach mathematics and computer science?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/99151/49593)

Comment: Thanks a lot @DaveLRenfro I'm at a kind of disadvantage because the seniors currently have the attitude that IT person is the expert at it. And I'm only having a Maths degree. I feel that I'll have to strongly convenience them that have expertise in that area as I did for postgrad too. Would be grateful if you'll can put in your ideas to present a strong conviction

Comment: Maybe there are things you can do to assist the teaching of courses in this area. Perhaps volunteer to hold recitation sections for one or more of the classes, assist with grading, etc. The possibilities for such activities will depend, of course, on your specific local circumstances.

Comment: Thank you @DaveLRenfro I'm willing to do even that if they allow me to. Currently they are keeping strong attitudes and kind of ego like, so I'm pretty nervous and thinking how to express this strongly